# overflow with left shift

Tags: c

I have a simple program where I have a few macros for bit manipulation.

One of the macro translates to following

```
unsigned long val = 1 << 0x1f;
```

Here, I am getting output as `

```
val = 0xffffffff80000000;
```

I understand it is some kind of int overflow. I am confused about the part about the final result. Why is the result coming out to be the one I am getting?

(I do understand here for some reason 1 is treated as int and when left shift is making it a negative int. But the part I am confused about the type casting.)

Comment: You might want to use `1L << 0x1f` to turn it into a long.

Comment: Yep that works. It is little sad that compliler can't understand it when assignment is made to long.

Comment: @Jester: That would be still undefined behaviour, as the shift is into the sign-bit. Actually, it has to be an unsigned integer: `1LU`.

Comment: @Olaf He is obviously using a system where `long` is 64 bits, as such a shift of 31 is not into the sign bit so it's not undefined. But yeah, since the expected type is `unsigned long`, it's better to use `UL`.

Comment: @Jester: Sorry, that refers to OPs version. However, using an unsigned is the portable way. One should never rely on the width of a base type (use `stdint.h` types if you need fixed width types).

Answer (score 6):

`1` is a *signed* integer, so in case of overflow it is undefined behavior.

According to the standard (emphasis mine):

> The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with
>   zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1 × 2E2`, reduced modulo
>   one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If `E1` has a signed
>   type and nonnegative value, and **`E1 × 2E2` is representable in the result type**, then that is
>   the resulting value; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.

Instead, try `unsigned long` value `1ul`:

```
unsigned long val = 1ul << 0x1f
```

---

> (I do understand here for some reason 1 is treated as `int` and when left shift is making it a negative int. But the part I am confused about the type casting.)

It could happen in practice indeed, if the sign bit gets set to 1. (But, once again, according to the standard it is **UB**.)

Nevertheless, let's consider a legal case (I used `short` and `int` since `int` and `long` have the same size on my system):

```
                        // on my system
short int s = SHRT_MIN; // 0x8000
unsigned int i = s;     // 0xffff8000
```

The following part of the standard clarifies it:

> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if
>   the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type

(If I interpret it right) since we cannot represent a negative value in unsigned type, we add `UINT_MAX + 1` to `SHRT_MIN` (in pure mathematical terms, without considering overflow):

```
UINT_MAX + 1 + SHRT_MIN // 0xffff8000
```

Comment: So, my case was the undefined behavior.

Comment: @agent.smith: You should be happy not to haved gotten nasal daemons.

Comment: @agent.smith Just updated to include a couple of words regarding integral conversions.

Comment: Thanks guys. This proved to be pain in the *** for me. This is a part of a huge code base and this was failing very rarely as it was undefined behavior and cases where left shifting by more than 30 was a rare occurance in my code base.I had to sweat out for 2 days to corner this bug.